# Verification of Result in ESQL

Tags: sql, error-handling, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Here's the situation:
I run a query that gives me one or many rows as a result in an array.

Like:

```
SET db = PASSTHRU('SELECT GUID,CONTROLNBR FROM TRANSACTION WHERE GUID > ? AND CONTROLNBR > ?' values(maxGuid,maxControlNbr);
```

That works fine but I want to verify the following:

Any result that has *duplicate CONTROLNBR's must have the same GUID*

So if my result set has something like this:

```
   CONTROLNBR | GUID
   --------------------
      5       | 123abc
      5       | 123abc
```

this is entirely valid, however this I need to return an error on:

```
   CONTROLNBR | GUID
   --------------------
      5       | 123abc
      5       | abc123
```

I'm not sure the best way to test the result like this in ESQL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find bad duplicates you can run this query in SQL, not sure if that works in ESQL:

```
SELECT CONTROLNBR, COUNT(DISTINCT GUID) as CountGUID
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY CONTROLNBR
HAVIGNG COUNT(DISTINCT GUID) > 1
```